# Get Average number of blocks for game

Tags: java

I'm new to coding in Java. I need to compute the average number of blocks per column on a board. The below is to count the total number of blocks within all columns on a board and then divides by the number of columns.

this is what I have so far but I think it's not right. i feel like I'm missing something.

```
public int getAverageColumnBlocks(Board board)
{
    int avgColumnBlock = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < Board.WIDTH; col++)
     {
      for (int row = 0; row < Board.HEIGHT; row++)
       {
          if(board.isBlockAt(col, row))
             {
                avgColumnBlock++;
             }
       }
     }
    return avgColumnBlock;  
}
```

Comment: This looks like it just counts the blocks. I see no division. That being said have you tested your method? Have you debugged to see what is happening "under the hood"? If you're not entirely sure that something is wrong, I recommend taking more time to test your method. If you are sure that something is wrong, please [edit] your question to include a clearer problem statement

Comment: you're returning the total, not the average

Comment: If you're not sure how to debug, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: You described correctly how the average is calculated. Be only aware that dividing integers results in an integer in Java: `1/3 == 0`.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I see where I made my mistake at and I am correcting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int getAverageColumnBlocks(Board board)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < Board.WIDTH; col++)
     {

      for (int row = 0; row < Board.HEIGHT; row++)
       {
          if(board.isBlockAt(col, row))
             {
                total++;
             }
       }

     }
    return total/Board.WIDTH;  
}
```

Comment: `avgColumnBlock` is not used and can be removed.